# requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am trying to implement a custom titlebar:

Here is my Helper class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Window;

public class UIHelper {
    public static void setupTitleBar(Activity c) {
        final boolean customTitleSupported = c.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        c.setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (customTitleSupported) {
            c.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where I call it in onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupUI();
}

private void setupUI(){
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     UIHelper.setupTitleBar(this);
}
```

But I get the error:

```
requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

Comment: Answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939814/android-util-androidruntimeexception-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-add

Answer (score 363, accepted):

Well, just do what the error message tells you.

Don't call `setContentView()` before `requestFeature()`.

**Note:**

As said in comments, for both `ActionBarSherlock` and `AppCompat` library, it's necessary to call `requestFeature()` before `super.onCreate()`

Comment: damn, this is a classy answer.

Comment: For ActionBarSherlock, it's also necessary to call `requestFeature()` before `super.onCreate()`. Reference: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/310#issuecomment-7350074

Comment: What if you need to show one layout without a title bar and then show one with a title bar? You will have to use `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` to hide it, then `setContentView()` for your first layout, then `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE)` to show the title bar again. That would be after `setContentView()` the second time.

Comment: Its the same case in AppCompat as @Saran said. You must call your `requestFeature` before `super.onCreate()`

Comment: with ActionBarSherlock it worked for me fine. But with AppCompat it crashes. And when I put requestFeature before super.onCreate() it does not crashes but it does not have any effect either...

Comment: can you help in my case this is not worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404146/when-orientation-changed-i-got-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-con

Comment: This answer doesn't help much...but what do I know

Comment: Its better to call before super.onCreate() in most of the cases. I faced in case of AdTapsy

Comment: This is so weird, I am not even calling this function and it keep having this error!

Comment: error message should be more specific - ' requestWindowFeature()' must be called before adding content

Comment: In my case `setSystemUiVisibility()` is same like `setContentView()` method. It must be placed after `requestWindowFeature()`.

Answer (score 24):

I know it's over a year old, but calling `requestFeature()` never solved my problem. In fact I don't call it at all.

It was an issue with inflating the view I suppose. Despite all my searching, I never found a suitable solution until I played around with the different methods of inflating a view.

AlertDialog.Builder is the easy solution but requires a lot of work if you use the `onPrepareDialog()` to update that view.

Another alternative is to leverage AsyncTask for dialogs.

A final solution that I used is below:

```
public class CustomDialog extends AlertDialog {

   private View content;

   public CustomDialog(Context context) {
       super(context);

       LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
       content = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);

       setUpAdditionalStuff(); // do more view cleanup
       setView(content);           
   }

   private void setUpAdditionalStuff() {
       // ...
   }

   // Call ((CustomDialog) dialog).prepare() in the onPrepareDialog() method  
   public void prepare() {
       setTitle(R.string.custom_title);
       setIcon( getIcon() );
       // ...
   }
}
```

*** Some Additional notes:**

1. Don't rely on hiding the title. There is often an empty space despite the title not being set.
2. Don't try to build your own View with header footer and middle view. The header, as stated above, may not be entirely hidden despite requesting FEATURE_NO_TITLE.
3. Don't heavily style your content view with color attributes or text size. Let the dialog handle that, other wise you risk putting black text on a dark blue dialog because the vendor inverted the colors.

Comment: Originally I posted setTitle() and setIcon() in the onCreate() method, but the edit moved it to the prepare() method which is called during the onPrepareDialog() method.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I think the following line `content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);` should probably be `content = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);`. So, `inflater` has to be replaced by `li`.

Answer (score 15):

I was extending a **DialogFragment** and the above answer didnot work. I had to use getDialog() to achieve remove the title:

```
getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu it was a while back so I dont remember exactly but I am sure it needs to be done before setcontentView() method

Comment: for any one facing the same problem: I added this code in onViewCreated();

Answer (score 6):

For SDK version 23 and above, the same RuntimeException is thrown if you are using AppCompatActivity to extend your activity. It will not happen if your activity derives directly from Activity.

This is a known issue on google as mentioned in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186440

The work around provided for this is to use supportRequestWindowFeature() method instead of using requestFeature().

Please upvote if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I showed `DialogFragment` in `Activity`. In this dialog fragment I wrote as in [DialogFragment remove black border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746766/dialogfragment-remove-black-border):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, 0)
}

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

    val dialog = Dialog(context!!, R.style.ErrorDialogTheme)
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_error_dialog, null, false)
    dialog.setTitle(null)
    dialog.setCancelable(true)
    dialog.setContentView(view)
    return dialog
}
```

Either remove `setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, 0)` in `onCreate()` or change/remove `onCreateDialog`. Because dialog settings will change after the dialog has been created.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the error exactly tell you what's wrong? You're calling `requestWindowFeature` and `setFeatureInt` after you're calling `setContentView`.

By the way, why are you calling `setContentView` twice?

Answer (score 1):

Change the **Compile SDK version**,**Target SDK version** to **Build Tools version** to **24.0.0** in **build.gradle** if u face issue in request Feature

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Dialogs based on an extended DialogFragment which worked fine on devices running API 26 but failed with API 23. The above strategies didn't work but I resolved the issue by removing the onCreateView method (which had been added by a more recent Android Studio template) from the DialogFragment and creating the dialog in onCreateDialog.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using AppCompatDialogFragment, my workaround was:

```
override fun onAttachFragment(childFragment: Fragment) {       
    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    super.onAttachFragment(childFragment)
}
```