# My app gets the error "Unfortunately, App has stopped." every time I load it

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I was initially trying to add a splash page to my app, and followed a tutorial on how to do so. However, now every time I load my app, it does to a white screen for a few seconds before saying "Unfortunately, [App] has stopped."

I was unable to find a way to copy LogCat, so here's an image of the errors which appear:

[image]

Also, here's my Manifest XML:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bipbapapps.leagueclickerapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainClass"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.bipbapapps.leagueclicker.CLICKER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Deleting the splash Java and activity from the manifest does nothing to help now (and when I deleted it, I did revert MainClass to .LAUNCHER .

Can anyone make sense of the list, and/or help me run my app again?

Comment: Your error is: "`requestFeature` must be called before adding content" http://stackoverflow.com/a/4250209/833647

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logs, I found that you should

Call the `requestFeature` before `setContentView();`

Comment: Damn, you StackOverflow guys are awesome.

Spent 2.5 hours stressing over something so simple </3 Thanks buddy!

Comment: Thanks Buddy. Always here to help each other.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it you are calling `setContentView()` before `requestFeature()`. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

LogCat should show you the problem. Click on all the error lines in the LogCat until you will be redirected to the problem.

I, myself, found that your problem could be at: Splash.java, line 19

Go check it out, hope it helps!

Comment: Yup, seems it was! Called requestFeature after setContentView() like a noob. Thanks for the help, friend!

Comment: Impossible to get 15 reputation from vote ups. I now understand. :P