# requestFeature() must be called before adding content in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-actionbar-compat

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

I get this error when i use

```
getActivity().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

from fragment.
I want to change actionbar style only in this fragment. So I can't set this in `MainActivity`. How to solve this?

I saw this question [requestFeature() must be called before adding content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250149/requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-content.But) it does not say how to solve this issue from a fragment

Comment: before you call setContentView() you should put `getActivity().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250149/requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-content

Answer (score 8):

I also got this error, working with a DialogFragment, even though I wasn't calling requestFeature() at all.

I was calling getDecorView() from the DialogFragment's onActivitiyCreate() as part of some tracing code I had written to help me understand how and when Windows are created. That worked fine, but a bit later in the fragment's life cycle its onStart() method was called. That called Dialog's show() which eventually called AlertDialog's onCreate() which eventually called PhoneWindow's requestFeature() method to request Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE.

Since calling getDecorView() "for the first time 'locks in' various window characteristics as described in setContentView(View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams).", this violated the requirement that "requestFeature() gets called before adding content in Fragment" -- the subtlety being that the content was getting added indirectly by my call to getDecorView().

The fix was to call peekDecorView() instead of getDecorView().

Comment: Just wow. You basically saved my live as it seems. We had a bug in production that crashed the app with the "requestFeature()" stracktrace. We weren't able to track it down the past two days- until I stumbled across your post. We were also calling getDecorView on the DialogFragment. I changed that and I guess it works! I'm still not 100% sure if this really fixes the whole issue in every possible way in our case, but it's seems like we are on a good way! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Regardless of whatever people are responding this issues still appear if you use AppCompatActivity as a parent to your activity.

For me this code throws error:  ​

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);
}
```

- Test 1 : `MyActivity extends Activity` ==> Worked
- Test 2 : `MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity` ==> Error "requestFeature() must be called before adding content in activity"

The solution for Test 2 (if you are using Appcompat) is to call `requestFeature` *before* `super.onCreate`. It would solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);` before the `setContentView()` in the Activity's `onCreate()` method. You have to add this line in your `FragmentActivity` from where your `Fragment` is being called.

Comment: There is more than one fragment.I want this feature only in a particular fragment.So if set this feature in the Parent activity all other fragments have this feature

Comment: @Sunny for that you have to make custom theme and apply it to your fragment class

Answer (score 2):

`requestFeature()` should be called before `setContentView()` in your activity.
Calling `getActivity().getWindow().requestFeature()` from Fragment is bad practice. If you want your action bar visibility to be delayed, i will recommend to hide actionbar in `onCreate()` of your activity & unhide it in `onViewCreated()` in your fragment.

Comment: I want to make a transparent actionbar only in this fragment

Comment: you need to recreate your activity in that case, or use some customview instead of native action bar

Comment: There is navigation drawer.So custom view is not possilbe

Comment: You can hide your native actionbar & can show your customview in case of this fragment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a separate Activity for this fragment and then requestFeature() on that activity before  setContentView() because requestFeature() is method of android.view.Window. Window features are for the specific activity. You can manipulate the window behaviors for a specific activity not specific fragment.