# requestFeature() must be called before adding content in Xamarin Forms application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing one sample login application using xamarin forms, I developed code in common portable project. When running in Xamarin forms android project, this error is displayed:

> Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

The code is:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);

        LoadApplication (new App());
    }
}
```

[image]

How can I overcome this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646468/error-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-content

Answer (score 0):

inherit your `MainActivity` from `FormsAppCompatActivity` instead of `FormsApplicationActivity`

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13779