# Where to set Window flags in android

Tags: android, flags

I want to add the following flag to my activity:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

I'm not sure if this line should be before super.onCreate(..) method or after. Is the order important, and is there any difference at all?

Comment: I think It was answered [here already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250149/requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-content)