# setContentView throws RuntimeException

Tags: android, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

I'v published an application in Play Store. It was regular but in last few month, there are many AndroidRuntimeException in Firebase's Crashlytics. Here are the error stacks:

```
Caused by android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Window feature must be requested before adding content
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.throwFeatureRequestIfSubDecorInstalled(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2309)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.requestWindowFeature(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1089)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:848)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
       at ****.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:78)
```

I'v tried different versions of appcompat library, such as `1.1.0-rc01`、`1.1.0`、`1.2.0`、`1.3.0`, but it not works. It seams ok in the source code of `AppCompatDelageImpl.java`.

Can anyone can help me to solve this problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And now when I call `findViewById`, it sometimes returns null. It's wired.

Answer (score 0):

[requestFeature() must be called before adding content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4250209/8516118)

Well, just do what the error message tells you.

Don't call `setContentView()` before `requestFeature()` .It happens most probably in your `Base Activity` that you requesting some windows feature after `setContentView`.

**Note:**
As said in comments, for both `ActionBarSherlock` and `AppCompat` library, it's necessary to call `requestFeature()` before super.`onCreate()`

Comment: It's not must-see bug so it's so wired. 
And in target class, I didn't call `requestFeature()` func to request some window feature.

Comment: As i have not your code snippet now but may be you call other than BaseActivity file .So checkout firstly.

Comment: If I called `requestWindowFeature` in `BaseActivity.onCreate`, the bug stack shouldn't contains the `AppCompatActivity.setContentView`'s call.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the question.
We have a track library and it will collect the Activity's title when activity create. And I adjust it to onResume by AOP.
Thanks you all a lot.

Comment: I found the *Answer.